# How to remove all URL hashes except first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

Well, on my site I have a FAQ where users can access specific questions through the URL, such that:

`https://example.com/faq#question-1`

And for this I use Jquery, such that:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).open();
}
```

But I want that if the user enters more than one hash in the URL such that:

`https://example.com/faq#question-1#question-2#question-3#question-n`

All hashes are removed from the URL except the first `#question-1`

How can I do this?

**Edit:**
if user type `https://example.com/faq#question-1#question-2#question-3#question-n` then change the url to `https://example.com/faq#question-1` so that only the first hash appears in the url and the FAQ only has to read a single hash.

Comment: Do you want to remove the hashes and then redirect back? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Twisty Only remove hashes from URL text, no redirect back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could something as simple as

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
var filtered_hash = '';
if(hash.length > 0){
  filtered_hash = '#' + hash.split("#")[1];
  window.location.hash = filtered_hash;
}

console.log(filtered_hash);
```

Comment: Why console.log is empty?

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán Because current URL of SO doesn't have a URL fragment. You can test this on your site where you have hashes in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```js
var str="https://example.com/faq#question-1#question-2#question-3#question-n";
var trimmedStr = str.split("#").slice(0,2).join("#");
console.log(trimmedStr);
```

This removes all hashes after the first hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like -

```
location.hash = '#'+location.hash.split('#')[1]
```